# python lxml: unable to find a node by tag+namespace

Tags: python, soap, lxml

Here's my XML:

```
x = """<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <soap:Fault>
            <faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode>
            <faultstring>Fault occurred</faultstring>
            <faultactor>http://xxxxx/PrivateOfficeDataService.asmx</faultactor>
            <detail>
                <details xmlns="http://privateoffice.manzana.ru/">
                    <code>100261</code>
                    <description>access denied</description>
                </details>
            </detail>
        </soap:Fault>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>"""

from lxml import etree

root = etree.fromstring(x)
```

Now, I want to find a child node of the root.

This doesn't work:

```
print(root.find('Body'))
# None
```

This works:

```
print(root.find('{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Body'))

# <Element {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Body at 0x10e6a1c40>
```

But this is too cumbersome, so I try this (which doesn't work either):

```
print(root.find('Body', namespaces={'soap': 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'}))
# None
```

How do I use this `namespaces` arg so that it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use the prefix from `namespaces` parameter to reference the prefixed element `soap:Body`:

```
print(root.find('soap:Body', namespaces={'soap': 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'}))
```